# Google map JS code - "this.activeInfoWindow.close()" - scope & this

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, scoping

In the following Google map JS code the "this.activeInfoWindow.close()" statement does not work as expected.  I think I am missing some important scoping principle here. Is there a better way to do this?

I am trying to learn better namespacing and scoping and OO techniques.

[image]

```js
    var data = {
      "cities": [{
        "cityCntrLat": "45.49463",
        "cityCntrLng": "-73.57819",
        "censusName": "MONTREAL"
      }, {

        "cityCntrLat": "43.65674",
        "cityCntrLng": "-79.39819",
        "censusName": "TORONTO"
      }, {
        "cityCntrLat": "46.80807",
        "cityCntrLng": "-71.21964",
        "censusName": "QUEBEC"
      }]
    };


    $(document).ready(function() {

      var myApplication = {

        // variable to hold a map
        map: undefined,

        // variable to hold current active InfoWindow
        activeInfoWindow: undefined,

        // arrays to hold copies of the cities markers
        gmarkers_cities: [],

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
        // initialize function      
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
        initialize: function() {

          // map options - lots of options available here 
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            draggable: true,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.64378, -73.50497),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

          // create map in div called map-canvas using map options defined above
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

          var markerData = data.cities
          for (var i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++) {
            var myMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(markerData[i]['cityCntrLat'], markerData[i]['cityCntrLng']);
            var myArray = {};
            myArray = {
              "available": markerData[i]['available']
            };

            this.fnPlaceMarkers(myArray, myMarker, markerData[i]['censusName'], "red");

          }; // end for

        },

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
        // create markers on the map
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //       
        fnPlaceMarkers: function(myArray, myLocation, myCityName, fillColour) {

          // create SVG icon that looks like a flag
          // The lowercase 'm' is "relative" moveto
          // the lowercase 'z' closes the path
          // more on SVG path command: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html

          var myIcon = {
            path: 'M  0,0,  0,-40,  20,-30 , 0,-20,  z',
            fillColor: fillColour,
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            scale: 1,
            strokeColor: 'black',
            strokeWeight: 2
          };

          // clone myIcon (not sure if there is better way to do this?)
          var myOtherIcon = jQuery.extend({}, myIcon);

          myOtherIcon.fillColor = "blue";

          // create marker and put it on map
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLocation,
            icon: myIcon,
            map: map
          });

          // create an InfoWindow
          var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

          // add content to your InfoWindow
          infoWnd.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + 'Welcome to ' + myCityName + '</div>');

          // add listener on InfoWindow - close last infoWindow  before opening new one 
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            // Close active window if exists                                
            // WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK??
            if (typeof this.activeInfoWindow != 'undefined') {
              this.activeInfoWindow.close();
            };
            console.log(typeof this.activeInfoWindow);

            // Open InfoWindow
            infoWnd.open(map, marker);

            // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
            this.activeInfoWindow = infoWnd;
            //console.log(this.activeInfoWindow);
          });

          // keep extra copy of marker info
          marker.available = myArray['available'];
          this.gmarkers_cities.push(marker);
        }


      };
      myApplication.initialize();

    }); // end jquery
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 350px;
  width: 600px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- <script src="../jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="data.json" type="text/javascript"></script>           -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work as expected"?  What do you expect it to do?  If you are trying to only have one infowindow open at a time, only create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "this" inside a function does not return your main object. I changed your code by removing `this.activeInfoWindow` and changing it to  `myApplication.activeInfoWindow` and now it works as expected.

```js
var data = {
  "cities": [{
    "cityCntrLat": "45.49463",
    "cityCntrLng": "-73.57819",
    "censusName": "MONTREAL"
  }, {

    "cityCntrLat": "43.65674",
    "cityCntrLng": "-79.39819",
    "censusName": "TORONTO"
  }, {
    "cityCntrLat": "46.80807",
    "cityCntrLng": "-71.21964",
    "censusName": "QUEBEC"
  }]
};


$(document).ready(function() {

  var myApplication = {

    // variable to hold a map
    map: undefined,

    // variable to hold current active InfoWindow
    activeInfoWindow: undefined,

    // arrays to hold copies of the cities markers
    gmarkers_cities: [],

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // initialize function      
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    initialize: function() {

      // map options - lots of options available here 
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        draggable: true,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.64378, -73.50497),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      // create map in div called map-canvas using map options defined above
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      var markerData = data.cities
      for (var i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++) {
        var myMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(markerData[i]['cityCntrLat'], markerData[i]['cityCntrLng']);
        var myArray = {};
        myArray = {
          "available": markerData[i]['available']
        };

        this.fnPlaceMarkers(myArray, myMarker, markerData[i]['censusName'], "red");

      }; // end for

    },

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // create markers on the map
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //     

    fnPlaceMarkers: function(myArray, myLocation, myCityName, fillColour) {

      // create SVG icon that looks like a flag
      // The lowercase 'm' is "relative" moveto
      // the lowercase 'z' closes the path
      // more on SVG path command: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html

      var myIcon = {
        path: 'M  0,0,  0,-40,  20,-30 , 0,-20,  z',
        fillColor: fillColour,
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        scale: 1,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeWeight: 2
      };

      // clone myIcon (not sure if there is better way to do this?)
      var myOtherIcon = jQuery.extend({}, myIcon);

      myOtherIcon.fillColor = "blue";

      // create marker and put it on map
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLocation,
        icon: myIcon,
        map: map
      });

      // create an InfoWindow
      var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      // add content to your InfoWindow
      infoWnd.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + 'Welcome to ' + myCityName + '</div>');

      // add listener on InfoWindow - close last infoWindow  before opening new one 
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        // Close active window if exists                                
        // WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK??
        if (typeof  myApplication.activeInfoWindow != 'undefined') {
          myApplication.activeInfoWindow.close();
        };


        // Open InfoWindow
        infoWnd.open(map, marker);

        // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
         myApplication.activeInfoWindow = infoWnd;
        //console.log(this.activeInfoWindow);
      });

      // keep extra copy of marker info
      marker.available = myArray['available'];
      this.gmarkers_cities.push(marker);
    }


  };
  myApplication.initialize();

}); // end jquery
```

```css
#map-canvas {
   height: 350px;
   width: 600px;
 }
 table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 td {
   border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
   padding: 5px;
   background-color: #F8F8F8;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- <script src="../jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="data.json" type="text/javascript"></script>           -->


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Tom! this works great !  However why does myApplication.activeInfoWindow work but not this.activeInfoWindow. Whereas both myApplication.gmarkers_cities and this.gmarkers_cities seem to be equivalent.

Comment: this.gmarkers_cities.push(marker) (i think you mean this) Is not present inside the click listener. The "this" object you get in the listener is the object where the click happens on. In this case it is the maps object and not your myApplication object.

Comment: thanks again. Any other suggestions for improvement? I am trying to use scope and OO code to make application more modular and avoid maintaining many global variables.

Comment: that's a bit beyond my needs. just trying to learn some advanced js concepts to better organize and re-use code. Problem with js is there is many ways to do same thing and is not clear better approach.